# Web Server Unable to Access from Internal Network

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, firewall

I have a web server that I am unable to access via its public IP address while I am on my internal network. If I am on an external network I can access the server via its public address. Also I am able to login to the server using its private IP while on the internal network.

The proper ports are open (80 and 443).

I am leaning toward it being an issue with my internal DNS server. My DNS server resides on different server and all of the client computers are pointed to it.

Any ideas of why I cant access this server via a public address while on the internal network.

Comment: You should be able to easily determine if it's DNS or not by doing a DNS query... are you seeing what you expect?   Likely your problem is entirely unrelated to DNS since you're saying you are 'unable to reach it via it's public address'.  While outside of my expertise, I suspect you're having a problem with trying to make a u-turn on your network connection.  See if [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6047391/nat-translation-not-working-from-inside-the-network-hairpin-condition) on StackOverflow helps you out.

Comment: What's the routing table (`netstat -rn`) on your linux pc and what's the ip you want to each?

Comment: When you say unable to access, what errors do you see if any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's usually two solutions to this problem:

- split horizon DNS: your internal DNS server on your LAN resolves `yourwebsite.com` to the server's internal IP address.  The *real* authoritative public DNS server resolves the external public IP address of `yourwebsite.com`.
- [NAT reflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation#NAT_loopback) (called many things by other firewall vendors like NAT loopback, hairpinning, etc.): when enabled, if the firewall/router sees it's own IP as the destination IP in the packet from an inside machine, it rewrites the source as itself (it's WAN address) before adhering to the DNAT (port forwarding) rules.

I'm guessing that you do not have either of these solutions in place.

If you have the option of choosing, I usually favour split DNS because it allows you greater flexibility internally for testing different sub-domain mappings to URLs (i.e. `*.dev.mycompany.com`) without having to expose that to the outside by way of *real* DNS entries and/or additional port forwarding rules on the outside.  With NAT reflection, you still need to add any/all port forwarding rules for the loopback to work, and you might not want that.

I would highly recommend you setup a DMZ for your web server; most business grade router/firewalls feature a DMZ port with rules already setup to permit LAN-to-DMZ, outside-to-DMZ, but deny DMZ-to-LAN.

Comment: Do different rules apply if I am running multiple websites with different domain names?

Comment: what rules are you speaking of?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I have been round and round with our IT crew on what is the best option for this. We ultimately settled setting it up using a split DNS. Working great now! Thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 0):

Check the internal DNS entry resolves to the external address.

```
nslookup webserver.domain.com
```

If not, you'll have to have your internal DNS server point the domain name for the server to the external IP address, but only if you have an internal DNS zone which is authoritative for that domain. Otherwise, a recursive query would most likely return the same record as an external request.

In case you're not a DNS admin, you could try adding an entry into your `/etc/hosts` file to test it works.

The web server responds on that IP address from external request, so it sounds like its bound to the correct IP so no forseeable problem there.