# Internal network drops connection to our own locally hosted web server on a disjointed network

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, virtualization, router, local-area-network

In time I have my ***internal*** network drops all connections to my locally hosted website. After rebooting the web server all ***internal*** connections to the website works again, but it is only a matter of time for it to go down again.

When we goes down ***outside*** connections, say by using a proxy or a VPN from inside would still bring the website up; but internally, it appears as though our website is down.

What could be causing this? And how would I go about trouble shooting it so I can fix it? It is as if I am running into this exact same problem every 4 to 5 years.

---

### Things I tried when it is down

**Pinging** domain name form internal network returns proper response with the correct IP (connecting over IPv4).

**Remote Desktop connection** from internal network to server also still works. I am connecting via Windows Workgroup Computer Name over a IPv6 connection using the *NIC_internal* adapter.

**FireFox** is not connecting:

> **The connection has timed out**
>
> An error occurred during a connection to *my_domain_name*.
>
> The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments.
> If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer’s network connection.
> If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that
> Firefox is permitted to access the web.

I turned my **Firewall** off (temporarily) still no connection. I then accidentally totally reset my firewall ... what a disaster ... thank God for VM clones and backups.

**Internal Emails** that are hosted by the server are also down. Did not check if externally they are still working.

I found [this similar post](https://serverfault.com/questions/524526/web-server-unable-to-access-from-internal-network). Running `C:\WINDOWS\system32>rout print` reveled some very old network configuration setting under *Persistent Routes Gateway Addresses*. I removed them using

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>route -p delete 0.0.0.0 192.168.10.100
```

but that did also not fix the problem.

---

### My Network Setup

It is a somewhat disjointed setup with two NIC's on the server end. Internally we are using the Window Workgroup network.

**ISP-Router** has everything wide open and is acting as a switch providing internet access to Internal Network Router and the website hosted in Windows-VM on an Ubuntu Box. (IPv4)

**Ubuntu Box** is running VirtualBox, which runs a virtual machine (the actual server) Windows-VM. The Ubuntu Box has two NIC cards. Both NIC cards, NIC_web and NIC_internal, are made available to the Window 10 Server in VirtualBox as bridged.

**NIC_web** is connected to the ISP-Router. The internet sharing through that connection in Windows-VM is turned off.

**NIC_internal** (Ubuntu Box) is connected to the Internal Network Router (IPv4 and IPv6).

**Internal Network Router** gets the internet access from the ISP-Router, and provides internet access to the internal network. All internal internet traffic goes out via this router (which has a firewall).

---

### My Windows-VM on an Ubuntu host

**Windows-VM is running**: Apache, IIS, [Simple DNS Plus](https://simpledns.plus/) as DNS Server, [hMailServer](https://www.hmailserver.com/) as Mail Server.

*NOTE: I changed up my numbers a bit*

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>ipconfig /all

Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : Windows-VM
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

Ethernet adapter NIC_internal:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) PRO/1000 MT Desktop Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 08-00-27-31-14-DA
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::6519:c34b:5366:56c9%13(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.3(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 386400285
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-28-79-28-9E-08-00-27-31-23-DE
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 209.18.47.61
                                       209.18.47.62
                                       192.168.1.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled

Ethernet adapter NIC_web:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) PRO/1000 MT Network Connection
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 08-01-27-99-C9-3C
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 76.80.54.3(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.28
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 76.80.54.4(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.28
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 76.80.54.2
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 209.18.47.61
                                       209.18.47.62
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled
```

C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\host

```
# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
127.0.0.1     localhost
192.168.1.5   me
192.168.1.6   nas
```

C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\lmhosts

```
192.168.1.5   me
192.168.1.6   nas
```

C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\networks

```
loopback      127
```

This setup usually works well... but since the last power-outage and some updates, things are somehow off.

Normally a server reboot fixes the problem. So, based on this, I am assuming that it's probably not a router or DNS problem.

---

### In Windows-VM

**nslookup** from Windows-VM shows

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>nslookup
Default Server:  dns-cac-lb-01.rr.com
Address:  209.18.47.61

>
```

brings up the ISP provided DNS server address. When querying my domain name from the nslookup `dns-cac-lb-01.rr.com` login, it provides me the correct IP address the domain name belongs to.

---

### On an internal computer

**nslookup** from within the internal network logs me into the Internal Network Router

```
C:\Windows\system32>nslookup
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
Default Server:  UnKnown
Address:  192.168.1.1

>
```

I looked at the DNS log files to see if I can spot myself hitting the DNS server, but could not see any entries in regards to my Internal Network Router's IP hitting it. Some other router outside must have this cached.

---

### Internal Network Router diagnostic tool

**Ping** works giving me back the proper IP.

**Tracerting** for domain name worked too, recording one hop.

I also rebooted the Router to see if maybe that would work, nothing.

I unplugged the NIC_internal cord just to see if it would influence something, besides disconnecting me from my Remote Desktop session, nothing.

Still no website.

Comment: welcome, please read [ask] and whats on topic in the [help/on-topic]  - however Windows 10 is never a server and make the question off topic imho specific it looks for me for a home user question which could be asked on superuser.com

Comment: it seems to me that the server has some 209 dns set that makes not yet sense, since you hide your network... really take a deeper Look into [ask] I don't see here a improvement

Comment: @djdomi Thank you for your input. I moved the question to the top -- it was buried towards the bottom. I hope this helps. The 209 DNS is the DNS the ISP provided me to use. I am not sure if I need to use that provided address or if any other DNS to say Google would also work.

Comment: @djdomi I totally restructured my question. I hope this is more helpful to readers now. Thank you for insisting me to look at the How to Ask link you provided.

Answer (score 0):

**I am not sure if this is the correct answer**, *but for right now it looks somewhat promising.*

I changed Apache to not listen to all IPv4 and IPv6 calles

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
```

but to listen to only IPv4

```
<VirtualHost 0.0.0.0:80>
```

Note: at first I uses `0.0.0.0` but later replace it with my actual IP.