# Apache 2.4 on Windows slow to respond to initial first request

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4, openssl, timeout, network-speed

I started serving pre-compressed Brotli files on my website https://www.filmfix.com/en/home/. They work; but ever since then, Apache is having response issues along *all* VirtualHost setups (not just for the `VirtualHost` dedicated to serving these pre-compressed static HTML files.)

If I click around right after the initial (very slow) loading, it usually remains responsive (or if I just restarted Apache) -- but if I wait a bit, it stops being responsive. And may take from 7 seconds to 45 seconds to reconnect. On occasion it would even time out the browser, waiting to connect.

What could be causing this; and how do I fix it?

My https://www.webpagetest.org results look like this.
[image: webpagetest.org result]

I do hope it is not related to my question from not too long ago: [Internal Network drops connection](https://serverfault.com/questions/1136739/internal-network-drops-connection-to-our-own-locally-hosted-web-server-on-a-disj).

I found a similar question on [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50803844/ssl-slow-establishing-secure-connection-taking-too-long) which gave me some more ideas, but nothing fixed it.

***Or could it be of my own doing?*** I am processing batches of 18 asynchronous calls from three different domain names, generating HTML pages that get minimized and pre-compressed and pushed out to other servers. The CPU hovers around 80% at that. Could it be that I am overloading Apache? We are dealing with about 5,000 pages.

[image: cpu usage]

From my httpd-default.conf file

```
Timeout 300
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 1000
KeepAliveTimeout 40

# reqtimeout module is disabled
#<IfModule reqtimeout_module>
#  RequestReadTimeout header=20-40,MinRate=500 body=20,MinRate=500
#</IfModule>
```

---

These are the different browser symptoms I observe:

### Chrome Timing Initial Connection/SSL

... and what I read when the connection is hanging:

> *(no information)*

[image: Chrome Timing]

---

### Microsoft Edge Waterfall

... and what I read when the connection is hanging:

> Establishing secure connection ...

[image: Microsoft Edge]

---

### FireFox Timings Blocked

... and what I read when the connection is hanging:

> Performing TLS handshake with *(my static. sub domain name)*

or

> Transferring data from connect.facebook.net

[image: FireFox Timing Blocked]

And I found that sometimes the Blocked time is just about as long as the TLS Setup time:

[image: TLS Setup time]

---

### My Setup

Server: Apache/2.4.39 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1c PHP/8.1.10, I do have 48GB of RAM available and the CPU is a i7-8700 @ 3.20GHz.

My DNS TTL is set to 3 hours, as I am about to re-locate files to different servers.

My httpd-ssl.conf file

```
SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300
SSLUseStapling Off
HostnameLookups Off
EnableSendfile Off 
EnableMMAP Off

<VirtualHost *:443>
    Protocols h2 h2c http/1.1
    ...
    SSLEngine on
    ...
    SSLHonorCipherOrder on
    SSLProtocol ALL -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1 
    SSLCipherSuite ECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+CHACHA20:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:DH+AES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS
</VirtualHost>
```

I tried setting `<VirtualHost *:443>` to `<VirtualHost 0.0.0.0:443>` (I am using only IPv4), but that did not help.

I turned off my Firewall to see if it is Firewall related, it is not.

running this

```
openssl s_client -connect www.filmfix.com:443 -status -servername www.filmfix.com
```

returns this

```
CONNECTED(000001B8)
depth=2 C = US, O = Internet Security Research Group, CN = ISRG Root X1
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = R3
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = *.my_domainname_dot_com
verify return:1
OCSP response: no response sent
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:CN = *.my_domainname_dot_com
   i:C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = R3
 1 s:C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = R3
   i:C = US, O = Internet Security Research Group, CN = ISRG Root X1
 2 s:C = US, O = Internet Security Research Group, CN = ISRG Root X1
   i:O = Digital Signature Trust Co., CN = DST Root CA X3
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
  ...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=CN = *.my_domainname_dot_com

issuer=C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = R3

---
No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signing digest: SHA256
Peer signature type: RSA-PSS
Server Temp Key: X25519, 253 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 5026 bytes and written 406 bytes
Verification error: unable to get local issuer certificate
---
New, TLSv1.3, Cipher is TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Server public key is 4096 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
Early data was not sent
Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)
---
---
Post-Handshake New Session Ticket arrived:
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.3
    Cipher    : TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
    Session-ID: 3D6884662...
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Resumption PSK: 5EA6E2B7D...
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 300 (seconds)
    TLS session ticket:
    0000 ... 3i.

    Start Time: 1691621025
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)
    Extended master secret: no
    Max Early Data: 0
---
read R BLOCK
---
Post-Handshake New Session Ticket arrived:
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.3
    Cipher    : TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
    Session-ID: 9BFE3...
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Resumption PSK: 38FFBF004D...
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 300 (seconds)
    TLS session ticket:
    0000 - a9 01 cb ...   a2 40   ....)..d...!.4.@

    Start Time: 1691621025
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)
    Extended master secret: no
    Max Early Data: 0
---
read R BLOCK
```

httpd -D DUMP_RUN_CFG

```
C:\64bit\Apache24\bin>httpd -D DUMP_RUN_CFG
ServerRoot: "C:/64bit/Apache24"
Main DocumentRoot: "C:/64bit/htdocs"
Main ErrorLog: "E:/log-files/apache/error_.log"
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-stapling-refresh: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-stapling: using_defaults
Mutex proxy: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-cache: using_defaults
Mutex default: dir="C:/64bit/Apache24/logs/" mechanism=default
PidFile: "C:/64bit/Apache24/logs/httpd.pid"
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have `HostnameLookups` set to `on` in apache config?

Comment: @RomeoNinov it is set to `HostnameLookups Off`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am back to normal.

I updated Apache -- going from 2.4.39 to  2.4.57.

In order to do that I had to first make sure Visual C++ Redistributable is updated:

> You must first install the Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015-2022 x64.
>
> Download and Install, if you have not done so already, see:
>
> https://www.apachelounge.com/download/

Running the update I did a repair, followed by updating Apache.

My website looks and acts a bit different using the same Apache configuration files as before.

I also added default index files

```
DirectoryIndex static_html/com___en___home.min.html.br
```

Comment: Nice!! Be sure to make backup or do the upgrade test in a clone dev environment first if you can.  You might find the ChatGPT steps need some tweaks or maybe does not work even though it sounds like it could. I'd do some more reading/searching of posts too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60324166/is-there-any-way-to-implement-http-3-quic-in-apache-http-server, https://www.reddit.com/r/apache/comments/o6a86x/why_is_apache_failing_to_implement_quic_http3/?onetap_auto=true, https://www.apachelounge.com/viewtopic.php?p=41699

Comment: I noticed you have Let's Encrypt SSL so wanted to mention might be worth a read on changes they make and/or are going to be making just in case that has any impact on this issue as well depending on your configuration, etc. for example: https://letsencrypt.org/docs/dst-root-ca-x3-expiration-september-2021/, https://letsencrypt.org/2023/07/10/cross-sign-expiration.html, and https://letsencrypt.org/certificates/... Just in case cert chains or any of that has impact on other firewalls, etc. along the hops on your side regardless of browser perhaps.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT Good links to have! Regarding https://letsencrypt.org/docs/dst-root-ca-x3-expiration-september-2021/ it suggested *they must use version 1.1.0 or later* -- but my previews OpenSSL product version was 1.1.1c; and now was updated to 3.1.2. **The update made Apache much more responsive.**

Comment: something to note is that it takes Apache now a lot longer to restart `httpd -k restart`